# appium doctor, warning about apkanalyzer is shown though it is included in the path

Tags: appium

I get this warning from appium-doctor.
WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ Manually install apkanalyzer and add it to PATH.

But actually, it is included in the path.
% which apkanalyzer
/opt/homebrew/bin/apkanalyzer
%

Can I ignore this warning? Or should I fix anything?